# Should I host my servers under the same domain as my website?

Tags: domain-name-system, website

While moving to a new datacenter we also want to clean out old design decisions that we now think of where wrong. One we are not quite sure about is to have our development- and test-servers under one domain example.net and our webpage under example.com.

On the one side this could prevent some not so determined attackers to guess e.g. the hostname of a development server but on the other side it confuses users.

Do you think this security-by-obscurity step might actually help and is worth the initial confusion of some users? How do you handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a change which makes it harder for attackers to guess where to attack you and simultaneously introduce confusion for the users I would expect overall security to go down.

Attackers are going to figure out your naming conventions, and it is likely only a tiny bump on the road for them.

On the other hand user confusion lead to more mistakes. And user mistakes can make you more vulnerable to social engineering, phishing, etc.

There are however other reasons why separation of domain names may provide security advantages:

- Validity scope of SSL certificates
- Same origin policies for cookies and scripts
- DNS search paths
- Web-proxy auto detection

If you are developing web applications, you need to research each of these areas in order to understand what your choice of domain names mean for security.

Comment: at least _Validity scope of SSL certificates_ is important for us because we use startssl. With these certificates a certificate for host.example.com is also valid for example.com. So when one of our development servers is attacked successfully the attacker might gain a valid certificate and secret key for example.com which is our corporate webpage.